# how to create logic that returns a certain number of cards based on the output of an API

Tags: botframework

I am calling an API where i get a set of information back as an object (e.g. screenshot). Because the value “bill_number” equals 2, I then want to create some logic that means that: because 2 instances of bills have been returned from the API (bill_number == 2) the next response from the bot should be 2 hero cards (in a carousel) with each card displaying different pieces of information: Card 1 to display the values of bill number 1 and card 2 to display the values for bill number 2. Similarly, if the value of "bill_number” returned when calling the API again was 4, i want the logic to then create 4 cards. I am unable to find the logic to create this.  (see image)
￼[information returned from api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vp5n0.png)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use dynamic adaptive card to achieve this outcome.

I did find this which appears to be looking to do something similar - https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/3674